# Undefined variable even after using isset

Tags: php, post, contacts, isset

I'm getting the following error for a contact form

> **Notice**: Undefined variable: sumNums in C:\xampp\htdocs\tedx\contact.php on line 45

I've already tried 'isseting' it.

**Below is my HTML markup regarding this.**

```
<form class="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
              <label>Name<small class="astrix">*</small>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
              <label>Email<small class="astrix">*</small>
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" />
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
              <label>Subject<small class="astrix">*</small>
                <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" />
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns">
          <label>Message<small class="astrix">*</small>
            <textarea cols="30" rows="8" id="comments" name="comments"></textarea>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row captcha">
        <div class="large-6 columns">
          <label for="captcha-code">Enter the following sum<small class="astrix">*</small><br>
            <span class="captcha-chars" name="captcha-chars">
              <span name="num1" id="num1">
                <?php
                  $num1 = rand(1, 9);
                  echo $num1;
                ?>
              </span>
              +
              <span name="num2" id="num2">
                <?php
                  $num2 = rand(1, 9);
                  echo $num2;
                ?>
              </span>
              <?php $sumNums = $num1+$num2; ?>
              <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sumNums; ?>" name="sunNums" id="sumNums">
            </span>
            <input type="text" id="verify" name="verify">
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns mt-25">
          <button type="submit" id="submit" class="submit"><img src="img/btn-submit.png" alt=""></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

**And the PHP:**

```
    <?php

if(!$_POST) exit;

// Email address verification, do not edit.
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}

if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");

$name     = trim($_POST['name']);
$email    = trim($_POST['email']);
$subject  = trim($_POST['subject']);
$comments = trim(strip_tags($_POST['comments'], '<p><b><a><i>'));
$verify   = trim($_POST['verify']);
if(isset($_POST['sumNums'])) {$sumNums = $_POST['sumNums'];}

if(trim($name) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class="fi-x"></i>You must enter your name.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!ctype_alpha($name)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class="fi-x"></i>Your name should\'t contain digits or speicla characters</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class="fi-x"></i>You must enter your email ID</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class="fi-x"></i>You have entered an invalid email ID, try again.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(trim($subject) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class="fi-x"></i>You must enter a subject.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!ctype_alpha($subject)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class="fi-x"></i>Your subject should\'t contain digits or speicla characters</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class="fi-x"></i>You must enter a message.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isset($verify) || trim($verify) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class="fi-x"></i>You must enter the verification number.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(trim($verify) != $sumNums) {
    echo '<div class="error_message"><i class="fi-x"></i>The verification number you entered is incorrect.</div>';
    exit();
}

if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}


// Configuration option.
// Enter the email address that you want to emails to be sent to.
// Example $address = "joe.doe@yourdomain.com";

//$address = "example@themeforest.net";
$address = "njshah@aixsol.com";


// Configuration option.
// i.e. The standard subject will appear as, "You've been contacted by John Doe."

// Example, $e_subject = '$name . ' has contacted you via Your Website.';

$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';


// Configuration option.
// You can change this if you feel that you need to.
// Developers, you may wish to add more fields to the form, in which case you must be sure to add them here.

$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name with regards to $subject, their additional message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email.";

$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );

$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;

if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {

    // Email has sent successfully, echo a success page.

    echo "<div id='success_page' class='success_message'>";
    echo "<p><i class='fi-check'></i>Message sent successfully.";
    echo "Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</p>";
    echo "</div>";

} else {

    echo 'ERROR!';

}
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Btw, the 45th line is

} else if(trim($verify) != $sumNums) {

Comment: if I don't 'isset' it, I get an 'undefined:index' error only for 'sumNums'. Works fine for other values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to answer yourself a question about the line below. Will the `$sumNums` be defined if the POST isn't submitted?

```
if(isset($_POST['sumNums'])) {$sumNums = $_POST['sumNums'];}
```

Comment: I got what you're trying to portray here. The hidden field isn't being submitted. What is the workaround?

Comment: You need to assign variable when there is no $_POST there. So like give else to it and assign `$sumNums = ""`

Comment: But then how do I get the value of $sumNums hidden field in the backend to compare it with #verify? I can't set it to a predefined number as it's the sum of two random numbers.

Comment: You need to add isset() on the $sumNums in the line 45 then :)

Comment: Got rid of the error by that but now it's not getting validated while it's a simple equality validation.

Answer (score 1):

In form you gave wrong name for `sunNums`  it should be `sumNums`

So, Replace

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sumNums; ?>" name="sunNums" id="sumNums">
```

with

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sumNums; ?>" name="sumNums" id="sumNums">
```

I have just changed the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Your input has

```
name="sunNums"
```

and you are using

```
if(isset($_POST['sumNums'])) {$sumNums = $_POST['sumNums'];}
```

Comment: Yeah that was a silly mistake. I solved it but still am getting the same 'undefined variable' error.

Comment: getting on the same line num ?

Comment: Yup on the same line.

Comment: hmnm I went through the code nothing wrong in it and the PHP code. What is the file name of your form ?

Comment: The file name is contactus.php

Comment: only one issue I can see is wrong name in the hidden field which should be sumNums instead of sunNums as `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sumNums; ?>" name="sumNums" id="sumNums">`. One thing also could be done add `$sumNums = 0 ;` on the top of the php code.

Answer (score 0):

in `HTML` name is `sunNums`

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sumNums; ?>" name="sunNums" id="sumNums">
```

but in `PHP` you use `sumNums`

```
if(isset($_POST['sumNums'])) {$sumNums = $_POST['sumNums'];}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this:

```
if(isset($_POST['sumNums'])) {$sumNums = $_POST['sumNums'];}
```

$sumNums variable is not defined. There is no such index in $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the value

```
$sumNums = '';
```

before

```
if(isset($_POST['sumNums'])) {$sumNums = $_POST['sumNums'];}
```

Otherwise, you can also replace

```
} else if(trim($verify) != $sumNums) {
```

by

```
} else if(isset($sumNums) && trim($verify) != $sumNums) {
```

I hope it will help you :)

Answer (score -2):

REPLACE:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sumNums; ?>" name="sunNums" id="sumNums">
```

TO

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sumNums; ?>" name="sumNums" id="sumNums">
```